# Multi-Vendor - Peer to Peer payments in credit card and paypal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, credit-card, opencart2.x

I am looking to implement an opencart solution for a client. They require a peer to peer payment system that allows a user to buy a product from multiple vendors. In other words the client will not hold any stock. They will just facilitate a transaction between the buyer and seller and collect a commission on each transaction. Has anyone here implemented such a solution in OpenCart?

i have paypal adaptive method, but i want credit card side also????

Thanks!

Comment: You can use paypal chained payment. This may help https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: Thanks Ved Pandya, but i have already paypal adaptive but i want credit card payment method for automatic split concept

Answer (score 0):

To process a card transaction (credit- or debit-card) there needs to be someone to hold the funds between the parties. It can be a e-wallet or a merchant with an account with an acquirer. The acquirer in turn talks to all the card schemas to make the transfer possible, often sorting out a few other things too, like fraud-screening.

As far as I know direct p2p between card accounts are not yet available, at least across different banks. So I think you still need a payment gateway to process it, and not to worry about the Payment Card Security (PCI) regulations.